# Is there a resource efficient way to load a file into a database?

Tags: ado.net, blob

I am trying to understand how to correctly load a large file into a database.  I understand how to get the file from the database and stream it back without using too many resources by using a DataReader to read into a buffer and then writing the buffer to the OutputStream.

When it comes to storing the file all of the examples I could find read then entire file into a byte array and then supply it to a data parameter.

Is there a way to store the file into a database without having to read then entire file into memory first?

I am using ASP.NET and Sql Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use .Net 4.5, there is [new support for streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556234.aspx). Also, see [Using ADO's new Async methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/20/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta.aspx)  which gives some complimentary examples.